# EJS layouts on express 4.x (migration)

Tags: node.js, express, migration, ejs

I had a testing app running on express 3.x with EJS for the views (instead of jade), I was able to create layouts and use them accordingly. But recently  migrated to express 4.x and all is well except the layouts. It seems that the layouts are not being loaded at properly or at all.

Is there some new module of some sort that needs to be loaded? What am I missing? I tried hard coding the layout onto my res.render parameters and didn't take. I even set a default layout to the app itself.

./views/layouts/layout.ejs (default layout for all views

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
          <% include partials/head %>
      </head>
      <body>
        <% include partials/top_sidebar %>
        <%- body %>
      </body>

  <% include partials/footer %>
</html>
```

./views/partials/top_sidebar.ejs

```
<a href = "/" >Home</a>
<a href = "/about" >About</a>
<a href = "/contact" >Contact</a>

<% if (!isAuthenticated) { %>
    <a href = "/login" >Login</a>
<% } else { %>
    <a href = "/user" >Profile</a>
    <a href = "/" >Jobs</a>
    <a href = "/logout" >Logout</a>
<% } %>
```

app.js (router call to '/about')

```
router.get('/about', function(req, res, next){
        res.render('about', { isAuthenticated: false, user: req.user, title: 'About' });
    });
```

./views/about.ejs

```
<h1><%= title %></h1>
<p>Something that gives about information.</p>
```

In this sample code the about view loads without the top_sidebar. Therefore I assume the layout is not loading correctly. Even if I force it doing: `res.render('about', { isAuthenticated: false, user: req.user, title: 'About', layout: "./layouts/layout.ejs" });`

Comment: Could it be related to an incompatibility with a version of EJS? I saw EJS 2 is not backwards compatible with EJS1, but not sure if that is related to your issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found a good module to replace my old method. I am using [ejs-mate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs-mate) for the layouts and such. The only down side is having to specify the layouts on the view file instead of on the route. But it should not be a big issue for the most part.

Comment: You can declare the layout in the route using `res.render('index', {_layoutFile: 'boilerplate'})`, just in case anyone else stumbles upon this.

Comment: Is this integrated on express or do I need another module. I'm using estate at the moment. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's part of ejs-mate.

Answer (score 0):

For 'ejs-mate' - I also figured out how to add a default layout file that is common across all views (you can still override it, per request, as mentioned above).

```
// view engine setup
app.engine('ejs', ejsMate);
app.locals._layoutFile = 'layouts/default'; //this default can be overridden per request
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

Using 'app.locals._layoutFile' may not be the proper express way, but it worked for me...